# Drawing multiple lines in Reportlab

Tags: reportlab

I'm working on function that creates PDF in reportlab . I try to draw string consisting of multiple lines. I have already known that i can't use simple '/n' and I have to change it to `<br/>`
but in my case it doesn't work. It write my string down in one line `lineone<br/>linetwo` with `<br/>` tag inside.I have tried also `<br>` and '/n'.

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Thanks

```
p = canvas.Canvas(buffer, pagesize=A4)
 
 test='lineone<br/>linetwo'
 p.drawString(100, 100, test)
 
 p.showPage()
 p.save()
 buffer.seek(0)
```

Comment: Is your string already split, or are you looking for automatic wrapping of text?

Comment: I try to learn how to break text in appointed places in reportlab  the same way as we use \n in python string. Now my string is drawn in one line. Thanks for editing my post.